# Encrypting existing buckets and their Objects

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3

I have tried cli command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://test2/ s3://test2--recursive --sse AES256
```

It neither works. It neither gives me any error nor encrypts bucket objects. Please help! 
There are thousands of buckets and objects in each account. Need a solid way to encrypt them.

Comment: If there's an error, could you be more specific? SSE (server side encryption) is transparent, the storage is encrypted, but you will never access the ciphertext itself (though it prevents accessing data with different account)

Comment: Please provide more information such as the error you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. There is no error when I eexecute the command from CLI. After successful execution of the command I took a look at the bucket and its objects. But they were not encrypted. Not sure what is stopping it to get encrypted.